# Linux find specific data to a file and entire system

Tags: linux

I need to find a specific data from a file. And I want to search it from entire system of my Linux. Is this possible?

Comment: The combination of [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and [grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) will probably do what you need. Tons of examples can be found all over the internet, so I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find / -name "*" -exec grep -q <pattern> '{}' \; -print
```

This command search from root directory(/); and so all sub directories.

You can replace your search pattern in place of  in command.

And it will print all files contains your pattern.

If you know the file extension of your searching file, you can limit search by replacing `*` with `*.extention` within command.

Answer (score 2):

The above  answer  will work but that will try grepping directories as well for the pattern which inturn will throw an error. The best solution  will be to search  for files only. This will  considerably reduce the  search  time as well.

```
find / -type f -exec grep -i <pattern> {} \;
```

If you are only interested in listing the files containing the pattern, you could pass the `-l` switch in grep.

```
find / -type f -exec grep -il <pattern> {} \;
```

If you would like to list both the file(s) and the pattern, you can pass the `-H` switch in grep.

```
find / -type f -exec grep -iH <pattern> {} \;
```

@alvits - Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I totally agree with your comment regarding the flaw on the other answer. You should also mention to use `grep -il` if they prefer to print the filename or `grep -iH` if they want both filename and pattern.

Comment: @alvits, thank you for the suggestion. I have made the necessary changes to the answer.